# Can not access the value of an array

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write a currency converter, where I want to get the information from yahoo finance and then save it to a database. So far everything is working correctly except one thing which is that I cannot access the values of rates[k], the only place I can access rates[k] is inside the button, which I don't want, I want to get its value and save it to the data base and retrieve it before the button is pressed, so can you please help me with that?

```
public class currency extends Activity{

    int item1,
    item2;
    private String array_spinner[];
    private String array_spinner2[];
    public Double rates[],
    obj4;
    public String API_URL2,
    rates_new[],
    s_query;
    public SQLiteDatabase db;

     @ Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.currency1);

        array_spinner = new String[38];
        rates = new Double[38];
        rates_new = new String[38];
        array_spinner[0] = "  USD US Dollar";

        rates[0] = 1.0;

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FunnyNames");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FunnyNames (id INTEGER, Email DOUBLE, FirstName VARCHAR, LastName VARCHAR);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO FunnyNames VALUES('0','" + rates[0] + "', 'Anita', 'Bath');");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 37; i++) {
            final int j = i;
            API_URL2 = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USD"
                + array_spinner2[i]
                + "%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";

            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.get(API_URL2, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                 @ Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
                    super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);
                }

                 @ Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    super.onFinish();
                }

                 @ Override
                public void onStart() {
                    super.onStart();
                }

                 @ Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONObject obj1 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("query");
                        JSONObject obj2 = obj1.getJSONObject("results");
                        JSONObject obj3 = obj2.getJSONObject("rate");
                        obj4 = obj3.getDouble("Rate");
                        rates[j] = obj4;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= 37; k++) {
            s_query = "INSERT INTO FunnyNames VALUES('" + k + "','" + rates[k] + "', 'Anita', 'Bath');";
            db.execSQL(s_query);
            String select_query = "SELECT * from FunnyNames WHERE id=" + k;
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select_query, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            rates_new[k] = c.getString(1);
        }
        final Spinner s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner23);
        ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);

        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <  ?  > argo0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
                int item = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                item1 = item;

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <  ?  > arg0) {}
        });

        final Spinner s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner24);
        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
        s2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <  ?  > argo0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
                int item = s2.getSelectedItemPosition();
                item2 = item;

            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <  ?  > arg0) {}

        });
        Button currnecy_convert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button12);
        currnecy_convert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @ Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final EditText input_currency = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
                final TextView converted_currency = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView61);

                if (!input_currency.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                    converted_currency.setText(String.format(" " + rates_new[6] + " " + rates_new[20] + " " + rates_new[31]));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a USD value!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add an Android tag to this post.

Comment: Are you getting an error at compile time or run time? What is the error?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, the value of rates[k] that is stored in the database is null. Which means that the s_query string cannot read get the value of rates[k].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting `null` in the database because your call to the Yahoo API's is asynchronous. You are inserting into the database before you get an answer from Yahoo with the array. You have to move the content of your for loop populating the database into the `AsyncHttpResponseHandler.onSuccess(String response)` method.

Comment: That would make `obj4` an array as well, which it is not intended to be. Also, this has nothing to do with OP's problem.

Comment: @TedHopp then what is `obj4` supposed to be? Whatever you want it to be, define it in a new line.

Comment: It is supposed to be a double that changes its value each iteration.

Comment: With your latest edit, the two declarations have identical effect. Why do you think the first one is wrong? (See the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) for an explanation of why they're the same.)

Comment: And now you just taught me a Java syntax I didn't know about.

Comment: I changed the answer.

Comment: Now its a proper diagnosis of the problem. +1